# How to do Mouse hover on Image in selenium web driver to get menu list

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mousehover, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to mouse hover on image to display menu list.
My `HTML` code is:

```
<img id="logo" src="/web/images/header/img_Logo_Topbar.png">
```

But I am trying Xpath as `"//*[@id='logo']"`. There is no response.
I am using this script:

```
Actions a1 = new Actions(driver);
a1.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='logo']")))
                 .build()
                 .perform();
Thread.sleep(1000L);
```

Comment: I am getting "org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: POST /session/770b5f2e-68b3-4dac-884f-47ed6d04f99f/moveto did not match a known command. Error message.

Comment: I don't know what language you are using, but in C# we don't neet to call "build" when do a `MoveToElement`, only the `Perform`. I'm not sure, but maybe can be it or the browser that you're using too. Some browsers (like edge) has not all the webdriver functions and methods implementeds

Comment: Which browser and driver are you using? If you running firefox with marionette refer to this -- https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/selenium-users/g8IK9AR7EIA.

Comment: It seems like a bug, you can use `JavascriptExecutor` instead to perform mouse hover..

Comment: I am using selenium webdriver and Firefox browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looks like a bug, I'm not sure what is the solution for this but if you want alternate solution to perform mouse hover on element you can use `JavascriptExecutor` to as below :-

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("logo"));

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("var mouseEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');mouseEvent.initEvent('mouseover', true, true); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);", element);
```