# How do I find multiple images using python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to find multiple product images on AliExpress.

This code works only on the main image:

```
main_image = driver.find_element_by_class_name("magnifier-image").get_attribute("src")
print(image_elements)
```

I tried to get all of the product images but it doesn't work. I think hover will fix my problem but I couldn't make it work.

This code should work but it also doesn't:

```
images = driver.find_element_by_class_name(("images-view-item")).get_attribute("src")
print(images)
```

Answer (score 0):

- check for iframe and code that is loaded after the site ( and wait for it to load )
- try if you can [select it via xpath](https://dev.to/endtest/a-practical-guide-for-finding-elements-with-selenium-4djf)

if it is really hover, then [see HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168614/how-to-do-mouse-hover-on-image-in-selenium-web-driver-to-get-menu-list)