# Hover over an SVG contained in img tag using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, hover, mousehover

The element I'm trying to hover is an SVG(Vertical Ellipsis icon) which is contained in a img tag.

I've tried using

1. Actions class moveToElement method

```java
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));
    actions.moveToElement(element);
    actions.click().build().perform();
```

2. Javascript Executor method as described in
   [How to do Mouse hover on Image in selenium web driver to get menu list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168614/how-to-do-mouse-hover-on-image-in-selenium-web-driver-to-get-menu-list)

Both of them doesn't work.

The structure of the element is like..

```
<div>
    <div>
        <img src="ellipsis.svg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Similar svg can be found at https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/three-dots-vertical/

Comment: I guess your problem is with wrong element locator. can you please share your actual page link and mention the element you are trying to hove over?

Comment: Do I need to take special any spl xpath for this structure to include SVG? Wouldn't //img simply be enough? The site is private and so link could not be shared.

Comment: I can't answer this question until I see that page from the dev tools

Comment: What error are you getting?you should post error stack as well.

Comment: No errors. It fails silently.

Answer (score 0):

there's a special way to locate svg tag :

Let's say you have a **svg** tag like below :

```
<svg id="some id" class = "someclass" and other attributes>
    <div>
    <div>
        <img src="ellipsis.svg">
    </div>
</div>
</svg>
```

**Then you can try this :**

```
//*[name()='svg' and contains(@class, 'someclass')]//descendant::img[contains(@src, 'ellipsis.svg')]
```